# How to Edit a website URL for existing App password on Safari Password manager?

Tags: ios, password

I have saved some items to my iPhone.

How can I edit and replace URL for existing Password on iOS password Manager?

Comment: There is a plus icon on the top, in the passwords list. Did you try that? It asks for URL, username and password.

Comment: Thanks @ankii, but I ask if can add/modify existing password url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s unfortunately not possible. A typical Apple annoyance, I was missing this feature myself already. All you can do is to delete the entry and add a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it.

I had the issue that a site uses a first page to get the user then uses a different url to take the pw. So the u & pw were called only by the second url.

I used ‘+’ to add the first page url, then same u & pw. When I saved it merged the two.